# Can I place my Android application here?

Tags: support

I have an Android application, which is written by me and placed on Google Play Store, Can I place that application on stack apps site ?

Answer (score 1):

If the application makes use of the Stack Exchange API, the answer is a definite "yes." According to the [FAQ](https://stackapps.com/faq):

> If your question is about …
>
> - the Stack Exchange API
> - applications built on the Stack Exchange API
> - scripts or browser extensions that work with Stack Exchange sites
>
> … it is welcome here.